# Backbone fetch doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

I am a little bit stuck on trying to fetch a Backbone Colection, I am a new to Backbone and I am sure that I've missed something simple, but do not know what.

Have some ideas?

```
$ ->


User = Backbone.Model.extend(
    urlRoot: "/users"
    )
  user = new User()

  View = Backbone.View.extend(
    tagName: "li"
    el: "ul"
    id: "#users"
    template: _.template("<li>...just a code...<span class='buttons'><button class='info'>Info</button><button class='delete'>Delete</button></span></li>")
    render: -> 
      @$el.html(@template())
    )



view = new View(
    model: user
    )
  view.render().el

  Users = Backbone.Collection.extend(
    model: User
    url: "/users"
    parse: (resp, xhr) ->
      return resp.toJSON()
    )



usersCollection = new Users() 
  usersCollection.fetch(
    success: (response) ->
      console.log 'success'
      console.log usersCollection
      console.log response
    error: (data, response) ->
      console.log(response)
    )
```

My "/users/ returns this Array:

```
[{"created_at":"2013-05-25T18:00:43Z","email":"user1@mail.ru","id":1,"updated_at":"2013-05-25T18:00:43Z"},{"created_at":"2013-05-25T18:00:43Z","email":"user2@mail.ru","id":2,"updated_at":"2013-05-25T18:00:43Z"},{"created_at":"2013-05-25T18:00:43Z","email":"user3@mail.ru","id":3,"updated_at":"2013-05-25T18:00:43Z"},{"created_at":"2013-05-25T18:00:43Z","email":"user4@mail.ru","id":4,"updated_at":"2013-05-25T18:00:43Z"},{"created_at":"2013-05-25T18:00:43Z","email":"user5@mail.ru","id":5,"updated_at":"2013-05-25T18:00:43Z"},{"created_at":"2013-05-25T18:00:43Z","email":"user6@mail.ru","id":6,"updated_at":"2013-05-25T18:00:43Z"},{"created_at":"2013-05-25T18:00:43Z","email":"user7@mail.ru","id":7,"updated_at":"2013-05-25T18:00:43Z"}]
```

And controller (Ruby on Rails) looks like this:

```
  def index
    users = User.all
    render json: users, status: 200
  end
```

And in console.log I have:

```
success
child {length: 1, models: Array[1], _byId: Object, constructor: function, model: function…}
```

Comment: thanks. Ihad read the docs but after your answer did it again and understood that i forgot to work with ```(collection, response, options)```

Comment: Interesting, is that typescript or coffeescript?

Comment: it's all was coffeescript.)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an initialize property in your View definition and bind the event to the object using "listenTo" for when the collection resets (e.g.):

```
View = Backbone.View.extend(
    tagName: "li"
    el: "ul"
    initialize: function(){
        this.collection = new app.YourCollection();
        this.collection.fetch({ reset: true });

        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
    },
```

then on the render property(method in this case):

```
render: function(){
        this.collection.each(function(item){
            this.renderWeeklyMenu(item);
        }, this);
    },

renderItem: function(item){
        var itemView = new app.itemView({
            model : item
        });
        this.$el.append(itemView.render().el);
    }
```

And "fetch" returns JSON data so you don't need:

```
parse: (resp, xhr) ->
      return resp.toJSON()
    )
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had the same issue and { reset: true } as argument helped me!

Comment: @mike927 Glad I could help!!

Answer (score 0):

Delete your `parse` function as your response is the format backbone expects by default. It will properly parse the JSON and treat the array as a collection of data objects which will get converted into model instances.

So your fetch is working, but you are not properly A) including any data from your collection or models in your view (so you can't easily see whether it's working or not and B) rerendering the view with the data after it loads by binding to the collection's `sync` event.

Comment: it doesn't make difference.
it returns:

success
child {length: 1, models: Array[1], _byId: Object, constructor: function, model: function…}